# Xcode Bot hangs on "Processing Results"

Tags: ios, xcode, server, bots

[image: Processing results]

I've got a real head scratcher here.  I just upgraded to Xcode 7.3.1 and all my Bots have hit the floor during the integration process.  For some reason or another the Bots get stuck on step 7 of 9 "Processing results".  I let it sit for about 24 hours to see if it would work itself out but had no luck.

Anyone ran into this problem and have any idea what a fix might be?  Short of reinstalling Xcode and Server on the build server, I'm not sure what else to try as I've tried a lot of random fixes that I've seen out on the interwebs.

Thanks in advance for any help?

UPDATE - The last thing to run in the raw build log is: 
Test Suite 'All tests' failed at 2016-05-19 13:32:16.765.
     Executed 131 tests, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 4.500 (4.592) seconds

Comment: Can you go to the raw logs and post the bottom part? It should tell you what was started before the hang. I have seen this with a certificate issue, and a code signing issues. Are you running the bots on a device or on the simulator?

Comment: I updated the main description with the contents from the end of the raw build log.  I was looking at this too but still didn't come up with a solution.

Comment: Disable your tests for your scheme or bot and see if your bot builds. I have had this problem with my xctests, but have not found a definite solution.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.  I have some Bots that run tests and others that don't.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Fixed**

Here's what I did:

- Stopped the server.
- deleted all bots from Xcode.
- Went into **/Library/Developer/XcodeServer** and removed (you will need Admin access):

  - Logs
  - Integrations
- Removed my derivedData directory
- Restarted everything and rebuilt the bots using different names for them.

Comment: It's crazy that this works.  While I don't get why Apple would fall on it's face and need this fix, it definitely solves the problem.  I'm okay losing the logs but I really wanted to save the integration history.  Albeit, I'd rather have a functioning CI again!

Comment: And then it came right back a couple integrations later.  Unbelievable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I think it happened after updating Xcode. Only solution was to reinstall OS X. After that I have not had any problems. I tried everything I could find from the web but there weren't any solutions out. I tried to delete everything that belongs to Xcode but I think I didn't find all of them. So my suggestion is to reinstall OS X. Copy all your important stuff to external hard drive or to cloud.

I know this is not the suggestion or answer you are looking for but it helps you out.

Comment: You're right, definitely not the solution that I want to hear.  Ironically I've got another Mac Mini here at work that I'm setting up in the mean time that happened to get a fresh install of El Capitan last week on.  I'm hoping to find a solution for this problem so I don't have to whack my current server.